# How to handle a click in a class method that has access to what's clicked on in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I find myself writing that type of code in jquery. "me" is a reference to the JS class I'm working with.

```
var me = this;
$('#elem').click(function() {
  var button = this;
  me.handleButtonClick(button);
});
```

Is there a more clear way to do this? With jQuery proxy I can do this:

```
$('#elem').click(jQuery.proxy(this.handleButtonClick, this));
```

However, I'm loosing the reference to the object that I clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to close over the `this` that refers to the object being constructed inside event handlers defined by that object is to do what you have above with a separate var, though most people call that reference `that` or `self`.  Basically, you're doing it right.

The value of `this` inside an event handler will be the target of the event, unless you (or someone else) takes pains to have that not be the case, but the target is also accessible as the `target` property of the event object passed to the event handler:

```
$('.whatever').click(function(ev){ console.log(ev.target.nodeName); });
```

See [jQuery's event documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) for details of what properties are available.

Comment: It would've worked well for me if jQuery was passing the object that was clicked as a parameter to the callback invoked after the click. However, this might have some negative consequences in jQuery's architecture, which I'm probably not aware of.

Comment: @Ignite it kind of does already...editing answer to include that info.

Answer (score 0):

To get more to the point of @DanDaviesBrackett's answer, `event.target` tells you what the element which was clicked on was.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var me = this;
$('#elem').click(function(event) {
  // in this line you are getting the control that activated the click function
  var button = $(event.target);
  me.handleButtonClick(button);
});
```

hope this helps